# How to match a block from start to end using regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to pick up the entire block from the starting title to the end title, but not include the end title. Example is :

```
<section1>
Base_Currency=EUR
Description=Revaluation
Grouping_File
<section2>
```

the match result should be:

```
<section1>
Base_Currency=EUR
Description=Revaluation
Grouping_File
```

Problem is that how can I formulate the Pattern for this match using Regex in java?

Comment: regexr.com helps me a lot in situations like these. It also gives you a cheatsheet.

Comment: could you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is something like below

```
<section1>
Base_Currency=EUR
Description=Revaluation
Grouping_File
<section2>
Base_Currency=EUR
Description=Revaluation
Grouping_File
<section3>
Base_Currency=EUR
Description=Revaluation
Grouping_File
```

Then you can use the following regex

```
(?s)(<section\d+>.*?)(?=<section\d+>|$)
```

Explanation for the regex is

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?s)                     set flags for this block (with . matching
                           \n) (case-sensitive) (with ^ and $
                           matching normally) (matching whitespace
                           and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <section                 '<section'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character (0 or more times (matching
                             the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <section                 '<section'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

If you want to match only for one tag then you can use

```
(?s)(<section\d+>[^<]*)
```

Explanation for this regex is

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?s)                     set flags for this block (with . matching
                           \n) (case-sensitive) (with ^ and $
                           matching normally) (matching whitespace
                           and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <section                 '<section'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^<]*                    any character except: '<' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 2):

If your *entire* input is of this format, you can simply split:

```
String[] sections = input.split("\\R(?=<)");
```

`\R` is "any newline sequence" and `(?=<)` means "the next char is a `'<'`".

However if that's not the case, from the regex toolbox you're going to need:

- the `DOTALL` flag so dot matches newlines too
- the `MULTILINE` flag so `^` matches start of line too
- a negative look ahead so you stop consuming at the start of the next section

Assuming "sections" start with a "<" at the start of a line:

```
"(?sm)^<\\w+>(.(?!^<))*"
```

Here's how you could use it:

```
String input = "<section1>\nBase_Currency=EUR\nDescription=Revaluation\nGrouping_File\n<section2>\nfoo";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?sm)^<\\w+>(.(?!^<))*").matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String section = matcher.group();
}
```